# FreeNas can't load kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, freebsd

My freeNAS Server has runned about 1.5 years now but over night it crashed and was not available anymore. No WebGUI, no Network Connection, no reaction on the console.

After resetting and autobooting i get the error "Can't load Kernel".

```
load /boot/kernel
```

- throw's the error "don't know how to load module '/boot/kernel'"
- the directory '/boot/kernel' exists, but no copy or backup like '/boot/kernel.old' or something else

What can I do now? Is there some tool to repair the kernel or can i paste 'kernel'-fiels from another installation?

- freeNAS is installed on USB-Stick
- FreeNas version 8 (how can i get the correct version, because it's not written in console)

I'm sorry I'm an absolute linux rookie.

Comment: Sorry for  your pain, but this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site http://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Consider using the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Comment: FreeNAS is freebsd, but not linux :) Yes, you can install kernel by copying it from distrib image, I suppose this one: http://download.freenas.org/8.3.2/RELEASE/x64/FreeNAS-8.3.2-RELEASE-x64.img.xz Please check what is your arch - x86 or x64 at first. ;) good luck!

Comment: You should boot your system with FreeNas installation media. And you should enter a command line shell for fixing required kernel and loader files. You can find required kernel image and configuration files on your FreeNas installation media.